# Make a datatable from DataGridViewSelected Cells c#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I found get datatable from "selected rows" but i couldn't find from "selected cells". I need help for it.

To solve it, i made two lists from selected cells. These two lists contain column index and row index numbers as you see below. Is there any way to get datatable from these lists? If not, could you give me any other solutions?

Column index an Row index list:

```
 List<int> cols = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.ColumnIndex).Distinct().ToList();
 List<int> rows = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.RowIndex).Distinct().ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably isn't important to know or distinguish on indexes here;

`DataGridViewCell` will be able to reference to\of it's `OwnerColumn` and `OwnerRow`, which will contain not only `Index` property but also type information and name.

I'm going to provide an extension method (`GetDataTable`) that demonstrates generating a `DataTable` named `"SelectedCell"`.

It will first ensure Columns are added to a new `DataTable` instance, as that will define the fields used by the rows. While creating rows on the new `DataTable`, we'll conditionally iterate over the initial `cells` (relying on unique column naming throughout) and `SetField`.

```
public static class DataGridViewExtension
{

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(this DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection cellCollection)
    {
        var cells = cellCollection.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .OrderBy(item => item.RowIndex)
            .ThenBy(item => item.ColumnIndex);

        var cellTuples = cells.Select(c => (c.OwningRow, c.OwningColumn, c.Value)).ToArray();
        var distinctColumns = cellTuples.Select(c => c.OwningColumn).Distinct();
        var distinctRows = cellTuples.Select(c => c.OwningRow).Distinct();

        var dt = new DataTable("SelectedCell");

        foreach (var col in distinctColumns)
        {
            // if selected cells are jagged, we may have to add support for, or specify, nullable types of column value type.
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.ValueType ?? typeof(object));
        }

        foreach (var row in distinctRows)
        {
            var newRow = dt.NewRow();                
            foreach (var (_, OwningColumn, Value) in cellTuples.Where(item => item.OwningRow == row))
            {
                newRow.SetField(OwningColumn.Name, Value);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    public static IDataReader GetDataReader(this DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection collection)
    {
        var dt = collection.GetDataTable();           
        return new DataTableReader(dt);
    }
}
```

To Test, here is a snippet where I created `Form` and Added 2 `DataGridView` controls.

```
public Form1()
{
    dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += DataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
}

private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.GetDataTable();
    dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    //var dataReader = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.GetDataReader();
    //var odt = new DataTable("OtherSelectedCells");
    //odt.Load(dataReader);
}
```

[image: Snippet of Form with DataGridView]

As you can see, there are control behaviors to consider and handle, including:

- selecting while cell controls are in edit state.
- sorting when selections are not uniform.
- column\cell type handling

Comment: Thanx to you and for your time. I tested now. It is working great.